# How to react to user tapping more than once

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using this method in `AndEngine` to detect  when a user taps on the screen,

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
     if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
         if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) { //Jump only if the user tapped, not moved his finger or something
              taps++;
                if(taps == 1){
             if(isJumping == false){
                final float jumpDuration = 2;
                final float startX = player.getY();
                final float jumpHeight = 100;

                final MoveYModifier moveUpModifier = new MoveYModifier(.1f, startX, startX  - jumpHeight);
                final MoveYModifier moveDownModifier = new MoveYModifier(.1f, startX - jumpHeight, startX);
                final SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(moveUpModifier, moveDownModifier);

                player.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
                isJumping = true;
                hipp_jump.play();
                return true;
             }
            }
         }

     }
    return false;
}
```

Sooo The issue I am having with this is that if the user double-taps the screen, then the sprite jumps twice which moves him out of the position he should return to. Because when it jumps twice the Y changes.

How can I allow the sprite to move only ONCE to each tap, even if the user taps more than once?

Comment: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html) Might help

Answer (score 1):

The manual solution is to set a delay (record a timestamp of tap), and ignore taps within some timedelta. I suggest using the high-resolution `java.lang.System.nanoTime()`

Especially capacitive touchscreens are prone to generate multiple taps even unintentionally. It is not handled in Android, and has proven to be a serious problem for our app...

**Update**: pseudocode sample

```
private long lastTap=0;
onTap() {
  long now = System.nanoTime();
  if (now-lastTap < threshold) return;
  else lastTap = now;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah its causing issues for a game project, So how do you implement this?

Comment: It is just my shorthand for onSceneTouchEvent or whatever method handles touches..